# BSONObj size error in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Assertion: 10334:BSONObj size: 27624158 (0xDE82A501) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: ObjectId('5329dd954a33b081be667532') .
I am getting the above error when I run my .js file.
 I have two collections city and country which have more than 15 million record and I am doing indexing on some filed on those two collections. What may be the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you either have a corrupt index or document.

I would try one of two things in the following order:

1. Repair the database
   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/
2. if you are able to remove the corresponding document with the id: 
   ObjectId('5329dd954a33b081be667532').

Comment: when we do find command, is it loaded into RAM ? Will it be beneficial if we exclude the _id filed, if it is not reqd, when we do query ?

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon similar issue. The field which I passed for `_id` in `$group` operation stage was absent in some documents hence, aggregation pipeline was throwing error of `BSONObj size: 18441867 (0x119668B) is invalid`.

Issue was resolved for me when after adding `{field_for_group:{$exists:true}}`
in `$match` stage of the aggregate pipeline.